# Laravel global query scope's withoutGlobalScope() not returning desired records

Tags: php, laravel

I have a global query scope called ArchiveScope that mimics the similar functionality of Soft Deletion. The apply method of that scope looks like this:

```
public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
{
    $builder->where('archived_at', '=', NULL);
}
```

So when I use `MyModel::all()`, it returns all the rows that do not have a timestamp (i.e. NULL). But when I want to fetch all the records (including archived), I still get the same result. I am running this statement in the tinker:

`App\MyModel::withoutGlobalScope(ArchiveScope::class)->get();`

Strangely, when I use `withoutGlobalScopes()` instead of `withoutGlobalScope(ArchiveScope::class)` I get all the records.

`App\MyModel::withoutGlobalScopes()->get();`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Defining the full class path solves the problem:

```
App\MyModel::withoutGlobalScope('App\Scopes\ArchiveScope')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Just found one case** when `withoutGlobalScope()` in Laravel not working. It fails when you use `find()` method (*maybe internal Laravel bug*).

```
//will NOT work!
MyModel::withoutGlobalScope(MyGlobalScope::class)->find($someId);
```

use `where()` method instead

```
//works fine
MyModel::withoutGlobalScope(MyGlobalScope::class)->where(['id' => $someId]);
```

hope it will helps!

Comment: Those both work fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by just declaring the class reference

```
use App \ Scopes \ NomeScope;


$a = Model::withoutGlobalScope(NomeScope::class)->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

As with other here I solved this problem by using the fullnamespace, however for a long time it was not obvious to me i was not.

I was using

```
StoreItem::withoutGlobalScope(App\Scopes\CompletedStoreItems::class)->where('id',$id)->get();
```

if I copied and pasted this into tinker it worked, but would not work in my code.  It turns out that because I did not have a `\` before `App` it was actually looking for

```php
App\Models\App\Scopes\CompletedStoreItems
```

which is wrong and quite difficult to debug.

Make sure you put the `\` before `App`

ps. Tanmay's code above works because he is using a string.